# Is there a random variable $X$ such that $E[ |X| ] = E [ X^2 ]$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, absolute-value

In probability, is it possible for some random variable $X$, that $E[|X|]=E[X^2]$? Can you explain why as well?

I believe the answer has something to do with symmetric distributions but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I can think of a really trivial case. Let $X$ be the constant random variable 1. Then $E(|X|) = E(X) = E(X^2) = 1$. Or let $X$ be an indicator random variable, $\mathbb{I}$. Then $E(\mathbb{I}) = E(\mathbb{I}^2) = P(\mathbb{I} = 1)$.

Comment: Another example: If $X$ is a random variable which assumes the value $1/2$ with probability $8/9$ and the value $2$ with probability $1/9$, then $E(|X|)=E(X^2)=2/3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives 
$$
\mathbb E\lvert X\rvert\leqslant \left(\mathbb E\left[X^2\right]\right)^{1/2}
$$
so the condition in the question gives $\mathbb E\left[X^2\right]\leqslant 1$ and not so much information.

Random variable taking the values $0$ and $1$ satisfy $\mathbb E\lvert X\rvert=\mathbb E\left[X^2\right]$ since $\lvert X\rvert=X^2$, hence indicator functions are examples.